# TRY CATCH for Cursor and While Loop

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to collect a list of certain numbers in a cursor and running inside a while loop and updating a table based on those numbers. If updating a number throws an error, I'm catching it using `TRY...CATCH` and logging it in a different table. And moving on to the next number. I want to take success and failure counts. I need to LOG in to 2 tables- `LOG_1` and `LOG_2`. `LOG_2` should be updated in case of success or failure

```
create procedure NUMBERS as
BEGIN
DECLARE VARIABLES
UPDATE log_1 table
DECLARE CURSOR FOR SELECT ANYTHING
OPEN CURUPD 
FETCH NEXT FROM CURUPD INTO VARIABLES
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
 begin TRY 
    UPDATE TABLE BASED ON VARIABLES
 End TRY
BEGIN CATCH
Update Log_2 Table
SCount = SCount-1;
FCount = Fcount+1;
END CATCH
SCount = SCount+1;
FETCH NEXT FROM CURUPD INTO VARIABLES
END 
CLOSE CUR
DEALLOCATE CUR
UPDATE LOG_1;
END
```

Will this work? Thanks

Comment: *"Will This work?"* The simple way would be to run it, in your dev environment, and find out.

Comment: I'd love to know *why* you need a cursor, it's very rarely necessary, you should be able to do a single update

Comment: I can do it but I need to log each and every record in log 2 table. If I do it in a single operation only one record will be inserted into log table.

Comment: That sounds like you're doing something wrong? You should be able to insert multiple record in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating the things. You can go for simple logic. check for valid condition and then go for update table and update Log1. For invalid condition, go for update Log2.

```sql
IF EXISTS(VALID CONDITION)
BEGIN
UPDATE TABLE ... 
UPDATE Log1 ... 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
UPDATE Log2... 
END
```

Comment: Let's say A - column is a primary key and D column is  Date....If I use Select A from Table where D > GETDATE(), I will get around 30 records.. But I'm updating the Table using A column. I use the A column value in updating the log too..

Comment: yes. you have to handle it accordingly using OUTPUT INTO clause and UPDATE Log1 using JOINS